# Typo in Cafferelli-Silvestre?

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, integro-differential-equations

I am reading the 2008 paper by Caffarelli and Silvestre on [Regularity theory for fully nonlinear integro-differential equations](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0709.4681.pdf), and something is puzzling me.

On the third page, an operator $L$ is defined by \begin{equation}
Lu(x)=\frac{1}{2}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}(u(x+y)+u(x-y)-2u(x))K(y)dy,
\end{equation}and the authors claim this is well-defined once we have $u\in C^{1,1}$ and $K$ satisfies \begin{equation}
\int\frac{|y|^2}{1+|y|^2}K(y)dy<\infty.
\end{equation}

However, just by taking $u(x)=x^2$ it is clear the convergence of the above integral does not necessary imply the well-definedness of $L$.

So is there a typo in the paper, or did I do something wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On page $1$, the authors say:

> The value of $Lu(x)$ is well defined as long as $u$ is bounded in $\mathbb R^n$ and $C^{
> 1,1}$ at $x$.

The boundedness assumption is not stated for a few pages after that, but reappears in Definition 3.1.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer. This solves my problem!